# PDO MYSQL error after moving database from remote server to same server magento is on

Tags: magento2, database, php-pdo

I am having an issue where when I go to my Magento site I get a 500 error and looking at the servers error log I see the blow

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so'
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Here is what I did prior to getting this error:

I originally had this magento 2.2.3 based website hosted on 
  an apache2,php7.0 based AWS EC2 instance.
  I had the mysql database for . this magento site hosted on an AWS RDS
  instance

To lower my aws cost I decided to move the mysql onto the ec2 instance
  where I had my magento site hosted on. So I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After going through the steps to setup a database (adding a root 
  password) I then imported the sql dump of the database into the website.

I then edited the env.php file to use localhost for the database host instead of the aws rds endpoint.

Lastly I cleared magento cache and in my browser went to my website to
  discover the 500 error.

Comment: Hey Jayreis, Can you plesae modify your question and write steps what you did. So I may help you.Thanks